# Jquery Datatable export to png

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know of a way I can export a Jquery Datatable into PNG/JPG format?

Currently a dashboard displays a datatable with some html formatting.  Ideally I want this outputted into a PNG so users can get the image to put into their powerpoint presentations

Ideally I would like this to work on IE 8

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest to use [`html2canvas`](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

This script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on the information available on the page.

[**Examples**](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html)

[**Download**](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases)

*Another possible solution:*

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

with the value in IMG you can write it out as a new Image like so:

```
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

Comment: You've asked for a solution and I've provided it. You didn't mention anything about browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks i know, my mistake in missing that information out

Comment: I didn't tried it in IE, so please do it by yourself.